# "User cannot be found." Error While Updating List Item

Tags: splistitem, user

I'm experiencing a weird error while trying to update the author and editor on some files in a site, but not all, and the behavior is strange and inconsistent.

## The code:

```
SPListItem item;
int newID;

item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = newID;
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor] = newID;

item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

I've also tried variations of using `SPFieldUserValue` objects, `SPUser` objects, `item.SystemUpdate(false)`, etc. from different articles I've found online but no dice. The "User cannot be found" errors still occur. The users do exist and the metadata is updated on some folders using the same users.

This is working as expected on all folders in the document library without a hitch. It also works on about 2/3 of the files in the library. However the remaining number of files result in an exception stating **"User cannot be found"**. The strange thing about this is that it appears to be throwing this error for specific users consistently, but those users also created/edited folders in the library which are updated successfully.

## Examples:

## Success:

A user is the author and editor of a document and also the folder that the document is in. The folder's author and editor properties and the file's author and editor properties are all updated successfully.

## Failure:

A user is the author and editor of a document and also the folder that the document is in. The folder's author and editor properties are updated successfully, but the file's SPListItem throws a "User cannot be found" exception while trying to update the item.

What is wrong with this? Or how can I approach this in another way that will not result in these errors?

## Edit:

Now here's an interesting turn of events.

After running the above code, **for the successes**, the user in the UI is updated, however the object model is giving me different results for the users from different methods.

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile(url);

file.Author <-- old author, from:
file.Properties["vti_author"] <-- old author
file.Item["Author"] <-- new author

file.Item["vti_author"] <-- System.ArgumentException
```

Which means none of the files are actually being updated all the way correctly... Haven't tested the folders yet.

## Edit 2:

I found out the root of the error, though it doesn't quite make sense to me why this would be an issue while setting the value...

The problematic users are stored in `SPFile.Properties["vti_author"]` as being classic auth users missing the claims prefix, though via the UI if you click the link it takes you to the user information page of the proper claims user associated with that same user account.

This leads me to believe this is an environment specific issue either with a remnant of the prior 2007->2010 migration or the classic->claims move shortly thereafter. Fun.

Comment: If it's only happening to specific users, perhaps the user accounts are corrupted? Is there any other common factor like permissions or groups? Off the top of my head I would say inspect their AD accounts for anything fishy and then run a full sync.

Comment: What's ULS tell you? Anything more?

Comment: Where are you pulling the UserID from?

Comment: The ULS says nothing because this is running in a standalone "run once" WPF application. The old users are FBA users and the new users are AD users. There doesn't seem to be any permissions related consistencies between either the old users nor the new users. The strangest thing about the whole situation is that when attempting to update a file's metadata fails, the metadata is updated just fine on the folder housing the file using the same user accounts, both old and new. The IDs are coming from the UIL.

Comment: The IDs are correct, and using the same user IDs works as expected for the folders, but not for the files.

Comment: Weird, did you try using `SPWeb.EnsureUser`.. maybe it works

Comment: What's the health of your UPS look like? Any errors or the like? Whens the last time it's had a full sync?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri EnsureUser() was run on every user being mapped over prior to this.

Comment: @Mike the last UPS sync was a last night, runs every night, no errors, but I don't think this is a User Profiles issue. There are no MySites configured on this server, and to be honest I'm not even sure why UPS is. The user information required for this should be contained to the site collection's UIL.

Comment: Have you tried using the Name of the person instead of ID? `item["Author] = user.Name;`

Comment: The name isn't always unique. In fact in this instance it will almost certainly not be. Migrating off FBA to NTLM and trying to map the old FBA users to the new AD users throughout the site. I've tried the SPUser object, the SPFieldUserValue object, and the ID all with the same results. I know the users exist, and the users that this isn't working on are able to be used to update metadata on SPFolders with the same users.

Comment: `user.LoginName` I'm sorry, those should be unique.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the code, because even passing the SPUser object itself would contain the LoginName information. I think there is something wrong with either those files or with those users, I'm just not sure which. I took a backup of the content database and restored to a different location to peak around in it, but I can't find anything standing out in there either. Not sure where else to look. I may just end up running code against those specific files to copy them and create new instances with the same metadata, but I still would like to solve this problem.

Comment: Let's finish in chat! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12580/user-cannot-be-found--error-while-updating-list-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reading the file out of the library and writing it back again with a copy of all the metadata. This was the only way I could get all references to the old users to be removed.

For posterity, the code I used looked something like:

```
SPUser author = GetNewUser(new SPFieldUserValue(web, file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString()));
SPUser editor = GetNewUser(new SPFieldUserValue(web, file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor].ToString()));
DateTime created = file.TimeCreated;
DateTime modified = file.TimeLastModified;

SPFileCollection files = file.ParentFolder.Files;
byte[] content;

using (Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{
    content = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(content, 0, (int)stream.Length);
}

file.Delete();

SPFile newFile = files.Add(url, content, author, editor, created, modified);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in properties)
{
    newFile.Item[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
}
newFile.Item.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: Did it resolve the issue?                                                        I see similar error while trying to access SPListItem.File.Author (User cannot be found).                                             Scenario: when I move item from site1 to site2, but not getting error, if I move item from site2 to site1.              Please help.